Flutter QR Code Scanner: Camera Continuously Scanning after scan
I have implemented QR Code Scanner using mobile_scanner package in Flutter. and in my app If I scan the QR Code it will navigate me to the result screen. I'm encountering an issue with the QR code scanning functionality in my Flutter app using the mobile_scanner package. After successfully scanning a QR code, the camera continues to scan indefinitely, leading to multiple navigations to the result screen.
Code :
MobileScanner(
        controller: MobileScannerController(
          detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.noDuplicates,
        ),
        onDetect: (barcodes) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return ResultScreen();
              },
            ),
          );
          print("QR Code Found!");
        },
      )

The expected behavior is that the camera should stop scanning for QR codes once one has been successfully detected and processed. Subsequent appearances of QR codes in front of the camera should not trigger additional navigations to the result screen.

"The expected behavior is that the camera should stop scanning for QR codes" - tried to call stop?

No I haven't tried this. Okay let me try

I have used .then after returning to the scanner screen. It's working fine for me If someone still find another solution then go for another answer. here's my code below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'package:ticket_scanner/Scanner/resultscreen.dart';

class Scanner extends StatefulWidget {
  const Scanner({super.key});

  @override
  State<Scanner> createState() => _ScannerState();
}

class _ScannerState extends State<Scanner> {
  final controller = MobileScannerController(
    formats: const [BarcodeFormat.qrCode],
    detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.noDuplicates,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.start();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> dispose() async {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          MobileScanner(
            controller: controller,
            onDetect: (capture) {
              Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then(
                (value) {
                  final List<Barcode> barcodes = capture.barcodes;
                  for (final barcode in barcodes) {
                    debugPrint('QR Found! ${barcode.rawValue}');
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return ResultScreen(
                              resultText: '${barcode.rawValue}');
                        },
                      ),
                    ).then((value) => controller.start());
                  }
                  controller.stop();
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


You have dispose your controller once get the data from QR.
MobileScanner(
                startDelay: true,
                scanWindow: scanWindow,
                controller: barcodeController,
                onDetect: (barcode) {
                  final String code = barcode.barcodes.first.rawValue ?? '';
                  if (code.isNotEmpty) {
                    widget.onCodeFound(code);
                    barcodeController.dispose();
                    context.router.pop(2);
                  }
                },
              )


I'd recommend to initiate a controller like this:
  final controller = MobileScannerController(detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.noDuplicates);

And then you have 2 options:
either call dispose() or stop()

So once you push a user on a new screen then stop the controller. If a user goes back call start()
The problem you are facing is caused by not disposing the controller

I have tried this but when I navigate back to scanner screen it gives the blank screen because of stop() or dispose() method. Or maybe I tried it wrong because I'm new to Flutter.

Once you disposed the controller then you have to initialize it.
Once you stopped the controller then you have to start it.
use RouteObserver and RouteAware to react on getting back to the screen
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html

Try this, hope it will work for you.
class MobileScannerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MobileScannerWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MobileScannerWidget> createState() => _MobileScannerWidgetState();
}

class _MobileScannerWidgetState extends State<MobileScannerWidget> {
  late MobileScannerController _scannerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scannerController =
        MobileScannerController(detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.noDuplicates);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scannerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MobileScanner(
      controller: _scannerController,
      onDetect: (barcodes) async {
        final List<Barcode> barCodesCaptured = barcodes.barcodes;
        String? data;
        for (final barCode in barCodesCaptured) {
          if (barCode.rawValue != null) {
            data = barCode.rawValue;
          }
        }
        if (data != null) {
          await Future.wait([
            _scannerController.stop(),
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultScreen()))
                .then((result) async {
              ///! TODO Return true when you pop on ResultScreen
              if (result == true) {
                await _scannerController.start();
              }
            }),
          ]);
        }
        print("QR Code Found!");
      },
    );
  }
}


Thank you for your response! I have solved this using .then function. I will post my answer below.

You need to dispose controller inside OnDetect method:
MobileScanner(
            controller: controller,
            onDetect: (capture) {
              controller.dispose();
            },
          ),

